# c++: Given a pointer type how can one recover the pointee type?

Tags: c++, templates

Given:

```
struct Field
{
  template<class T> T Value() const
  {
    // ???
  }
  template<class S> S SimpleValue() const
  {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const S *>(GetVoidPointerToTheActualValue());
  }
  template<class P> const P *PointerValue() const
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<const P *>(GetVoidPointerToTheActualValue());
  }
};
```

How do I implement the `Field::Value<T>()` method, so that the compiler automatically dispatches to:

- `Field::PointerValue<P>` if `T` is actually `P*`
- `Field::SimpleValue<S>` otherwise

In addition it is guaranteed, that `T` is neither a reference nor a pointer-to-pointer type.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

@Grizzly - I have tried your suggestion, unfortunately it fails during the compilation of `Value<LPCWSTR>()`:

```
1>  playmssqlce.cpp
1>c:\dev\internal\playmssqlce\playmssqlce.cpp(75): error C2668: 'sqlserver::Field::Value' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\dev\internal\playmssqlce\sqlserverfield.h(19): could be 'std::tr1::enable_if<_Test,_Type> sqlserver::Field::Value<LPCWSTR>(void) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Test=false,
1>              _Type=LPCWSTR
1>          ]
1>          c:\dev\internal\playmssqlce\sqlserverfield.h(18): or       'std::tr1::enable_if<_Test,_Type> sqlserver::Field::Value<LPCWSTR>(void) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Test=true,
1>              _Type=LPCWSTR
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(void)'
```

It is unclear to me why, because your advice feels right. BTW, I am using Visual Studio 2010.

**EDIT2**

After fixing the stupid mistake, I still have problems. So, here is what I have:

```
struct Field
{
  template<class T> typename enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type Value() const { return PointerValue(); }
  template<class T> typename enable_if<!is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type Value() const { return SimpleValue(); }
  template<class T> T SimpleValue() const         { return *reinterpret_cast<const T *>(GetVoidPointerToTheActualValue()); }
  template<class T> const T *PointerValue() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T *>(GetVoidPointerToTheActualValue()); }
};
```

I am trying to compile `f.Value<const wchar_t *>()`, but getting this:

```
1>  playmssqlce.cpp
1>c:\dev\internal\playmssqlce\sqlserverfield.h(18): error C2783: 'const T *sqlserver::Field::PointerValue(void) const' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
1>          c:\dev\internal\playmssqlce\sqlserverfield.h(42) : see declaration of 'sqlserver::Field::PointerValue'
1>          c:\dev\internal\playmssqlce\playmssqlce.cpp(75) : see reference to function template instantiation 'const wchar_t *sqlserver::Field::Value<const wchar_t*>(void) const' being compiled
```

What am I doing wrong now?

Thanks.

**EDIT3**

Stupid me. Noticed the change by Grizzly:

```
template<class T> typename enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type Value() const { return PointerValue<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>(); }
template<class T> typename enable_if<!is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type Value() const { return SimpleValue<T>(); }
```

Works now.

Comment: Regarding edit: didn't you forget `::type` after `enable_if<...>`?

Comment: Yep, I did, but still there are problems - see the update.

Comment: @mark: Well, how do you call the `Value` function?

Comment: Oh, apparently I haven't fixed it all. Stupid me. Works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enable_if`:

```
struct Field {
  /*Other methods of Field*/
  template<class T> 
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type Value() const {
    return this->PointerValue<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>();
  }
  template<class T> 
  typename  std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type Value() const {
    return this->SimpleValue<T>();
  }

};
```

Of course `std::enable_if`, `std::is_pointer<T>` and `std::remove_pointer<T>` are only availible if you have `C++11`. If you don't you can use either `std::tr1::is_pointer` or `boost::is_pointer` together with either `boost::enable_if` (or `boost::enable_if_c`) or a self written `enable_if` (look [here](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#overloading) for how to do it, it's pretty trivial). `remove_pointer` is also availible as both `std::tr1::remove_pointer` and `boost::remove_pointer`.

However depending on what you want it might still not do what you want, since the way I wrote it you need to pass `const P*` to `Value()`, since that is what `PointerValue()` returns. If you want to pass `P*` and get `const P*` back, you can change it to following:

```
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_pointer<T>::value, typename 
    std::add_const<typename 
        std::remove_pointer<T>::type
    >::type*
>::type Value() const;
```

Once again use `std::tr1::add_const` or `boost::add_const` if you don't have c++11

Comment: You couls also overload an internal impl function on `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` and pass `typename std::is_pointer<T>::type()`.

Comment: @mark: you need to use `enable_if` as `typename enable_if<Cond, Type>::type`, from your error I'd guess you used just `enable_if<Cond, Type>` as return type. Furthermore I thought that `enable_if` was not part of `tr1` (I might be wrong though)

Answer (score 1):

You want your function template to have two different behaviors depending on the type of argument it is instantiated with. This calls for template specialization. In this case, since you want to specialize for all pointer types, what you need is partial template specialization.

Function templates does not support partial specializations: a solution would be to use an helper class template to perform the operations:

```
template < typename T >
struct getValue
{
    static T apply() { default behavior }
};

template < typename T>
struct getValue< T * >
{
    static T * apply() { behavior for pointer types }
};
```

This helper class can then be used in your member function template. However, since you need to access some data in the `Field` instance, you will need to pass it the the helper class.

Another thing is that the return type of `Field::value` depends on the template parameter. To determine what is the correct return type, a good solution is to have a typedef in the helper class, that can be retrieved when declaring `Field::value`.

Here is the complete code of this solution:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace detail { template < typename T > struct getValue; }

class Field
{
  public:
    void * getVoidPointerToTheActualValue() const;

    template< class T >
    typename detail::getValue< T >::result_type value() const;

  private:
    void * actualValue_;
};

namespace detail {

template < typename T >
struct getValue
{
    typedef T result_type;

    static result_type apply( Field const & f )
    {
        std::cout << "simpleValue" << '\n';
        return *reinterpret_cast< const T * >( 
                f.getVoidPointerToTheActualValue() );
    }
};

template < typename T >
struct getValue< T * >
{
    typedef T const * result_type;

    static result_type apply( Field const & f )
    {
        std::cout << "pointerValue" << '\n';
        return reinterpret_cast< const T * >(
                f.getVoidPointerToTheActualValue() );
    }
};

} //namespace detail


void * Field::getVoidPointerToTheActualValue() const
{
    return actualValue_;
}

template< class T >
typename detail::getValue< T >::result_type Field::value() const
{
    return detail::getValue< T >::apply( *this );
}


int main()
{
    Field f;
    f.value< int >();   //prints "simpleValue"
    f.value< int * >(); //prints "pointerValue"
}
```